# Excel is being closed while connecting to Oracle using VBA

Tags: oracle, excel, database-connection, vba

I am trying to connect to Oracle using Excel VBA but when the code is run, Excel is closed and reopened at line *MsgBox rs.recordCount*

```
Sub Ora_Connection()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim query As String
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    On Error GoTo final1
    query = "Select * from EMP where EMP_NO='998234'"
    strcon = "Driver={Oracle in OraClient11g_home1};Dbq=smqa;Uid=MyUserID;Pwd=MyPassword;"
    con.Open (strcon)
    rs.CursorType = 1
    rs.Open query, con
    rs.MoveLast
    MsgBox rs.recordCount
    rs.Close
    Set s = Nothing
    con.Close
    Set con = Nothing
    final1:
    MsgBox err.Number & "    " & err.Description
End Sub
```

I am running this code on Windows 7 and trying to connect Oracle 11g. Do I need any additional setup to connect Oracle Db using Excel VBA or is something wrong in the code?